# New [mvn] tag with only one question; Vote for synonym or edit out?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I saw [mvn](/questions/tagged/mvn) in the *New tags* section of the 10k tools. It's an obvious duplicate/synonym of [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), which at the time I visited already had a synonym vote for [mvn](/questions/tagged/mvn).

In this case, should we vote for tag synonyms, or edit the new tag out of the question (and possibly flag the tag for deletion - if possible, don't even know if/how that can be done).

This is just personal opinion and possibly debatable, but [mvn](/questions/tagged/mvn) should either be about the command-line program called `mvn` (that is, if it makes sense on its own as a tag), or not exist.

*Note: I already [edited the tag out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21311012/1) of the question, I just would like to know which would be the right course of action in this case.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit it out, then the tag will auto destruct after a while if nothing is using it.

If there is an executable called mvn.exe and the tag was intended for that then the author should have used that. Otherwise it simply looks like either someone being lazy, or possibly someone's rather misguided attempt to get a badge.

Comment: Great, didn't know how tags get destroyed. Looking at the tag editor's profile it does indeed look like a badge chase. There is a mvn.exe (which is how you actually use Maven), and it's probably not worthy of an own tag, anyway. I guess there isn't a specific way to flag other potentially unnecessary tags other than raising a custom flag on an arbitrary post by said user.

Comment: FWIW, the `mvn` tag is on my list of tags I keep dead daily.  There have never really been enough questions in it for anyone to propose making it a synonym of [tag:maven], which is what really should happen.  Someone recreates it about once every other week.